# API - Multitenancy - Works with Postman only

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

When i login through the flutter client, i receive the previous users content.

I assume this is due to an issue in the logout function.

Everything works fine in Postman(Relevant user content is presented in Postman)

**lib\providers\auth_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:demo_app/services/api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  late String token;

  ApiService apiService = ApiService('');

  Future<void> register(String name, String email, String password, String passwordConfirm, String deviceName) async{
  token = await apiService.register(name, email, password, passwordConfirm, deviceName);
  isAuthenticated = true;
  notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logIn(String email, String password, String deviceName) async {
    token = await apiService.logIn(email, password, deviceName);
    isAuthenticated = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    token = '';
    isAuthenticated = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The api.dart file looks like this

**lib\services\api.dart**

```
    class ApiService{
    
      late String token;
    
      ApiService(this.token);
    
      final String baseUrl = 'http://flutter-api.test/api/';
    
      Future<List<Category>> fetchCategories() async {
        http.Response response =
            await http.get(Uri.parse('${baseUrl}categories'),
            headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
              HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
              HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
            },
          );
    
        List categories = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
        return categories.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
      }
    
    ..
    ..
    
    
    Future<String> logIn(String email, String password, String deviceName) async {
        String uri = '${baseUrl}auth/login';
        http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri),
          headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
              HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',          
            },
          body: jsonEncode({
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'device_name': deviceName
          })
        );
        if(response.statusCode == 422){
          Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
          Map<String, dynamic> errors = body['errors'];
          String errorMessage = '';
          errors.forEach((key, value){
            value.forEach((element){
              errorMessage += element + '\n';
            });
          });
    
          throw Exception(errorMessage);
        }
    
        return response.body;
      }
    }
```

The category_privder.dart file looks like this

**lib\providers\category_provider.dart**

```
    import 'package:demo_app/models/category.dart';
    import 'package:demo_app/providers/auth_provider.dart';
    import 'package:demo_app/services/api.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class CategoryProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
      List<Category> categories = [];
      late ApiService apiService;
      late AuthProvider authProvider;
    
      CategoryProvider(this.authProvider){
        apiService = ApiService(authProvider.token);
    
        init();
      }
    
      Future init() async{
        categories = await apiService.fetchCategories();
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      Future<void> addCategory(String name) async{
        try{
          Category addedCategory = await apiService.addCategory(name);
          categories.add(addedCategory);
    
          notifyListeners();
        } catch(e){
          await authProvider.logOut();
          // ignore: avoid_print
          // print(e);
        }
      }
    
      Future<void> updateCategory(Category category) async{
        try{
          Category updatedCategory = await apiService.updateCategory(category);
          int index = categories.indexOf(category);
          categories[index] = updatedCategory;
    
          notifyListeners();
        } catch(e){
          await authProvider.logOut();
        }
      }
    
      Future<void> deleteCategory(Category category) async{
        try{
          await apiService.deleteCategory(category.id);
          categories.remove(category);      
          notifyListeners();
        } catch(e){
          await authProvider.logOut();
        }
      }
       
    
    }
```

I am trying to get the flutter client to display the relevant categories of a particular user. The Laravel part seems to work well, because everything works fine in Postman

Maybe it is something to do with the **BuildContext**

How can i solve this issue

**lib\screens\login.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:demo_app/providers/auth_provider.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'dart:async';
// import 'dart:developer' as developer;

// import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';



class Login extends StatefulWidget{
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState(); // Alternative for _LoginState createState()  => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  String errorMessage = '';
  String? deviceName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDeviceName();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Login'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Card(
                elevation: 8,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),                
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[                  
                      TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        controller: emailController,
                        validator: (String? value){
                          if(value!.isEmpty){
                            return 'Enter Email';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onChanged: (text) => setState(() => errorMessage = ''),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Email',
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        obscureText: true,
                        enableSuggestions: false,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        controller: passwordController,
                        validator: (String? value){
                          if(value!.isEmpty){
                            return 'Enter password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onChanged: (text) => setState(() => errorMessage = ''),
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Password',
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => submit(),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 36)
                        ),
                        child: const Text('Login'),
                      ),
                      Text(errorMessage, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');                            
                          }, 
                          child: const Text("Register New User", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                          ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), 
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),        
      );
    }

    Future<void> submit() async{
      final form = _formKey.currentState;

      if(!form!.validate()){
        return;
      }

      final AuthProvider provider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
      try {                
        await provider.logIn(
          emailController.text,
          passwordController.text,
          deviceName ?? 'Some Device'
        );

      } catch(e){
        setState(() {          
          errorMessage = e.toString().replaceAll('Exception:', '');
        });
      }

    }
    
    Future<void> getDeviceName() async{
      final deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();

      try{
        if (Platform.isAndroid){
          var build = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
          setState((){
            deviceName = build.model;
          });
        }
        else if (Platform.isIOS){
          var build = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
          setState((){
            deviceName = build.model;
          });
        }
      } on PlatformException{
        setState((){
          deviceName = 'Failed to get platform version';
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shared prefrences presist data to disk. So you need to remove delete the token from shared prefrences on logout.

Comment: @RadiantOne i took away the shared preferences away to identify the issue and yet the problem remains the same.